# How can I find a elasticloadbalancer by its arn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I got an error when I deploy my service to AWS:

```
Error: Error deleting Target Group: ResourceInUse: Target group 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:800371615020:targetgroup/api-test/2b44ce2b1a03c361' is currently in use by a listener or a rule
    status code: 400, request id: 4f64ea2b-d9cc-11e9-85ff-9f21b19f7303
```

It looks like a elasticsearch load balance is still in use. But how can I find this resource on my AWS? I have used the command `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers` and `aws elb describe-load-balancers` but none of them print any resource relates to the one shown in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Error deleting Target Group: ResourceInUse: Target group
>   'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:800371615020:targetgroup/api-test/2b44ce2b1a03c361'
>   is currently in use by a listener or a rule

You can not delete Target group if still attached with any LB as a listener.

You can find the LB of the target group using this command.

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --target-group-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:800371615020:targetgroup/api-test/2b44ce2b1a03c361
```

This Json response will containe the ARN of LB, use that ARN and get info of LB

```
aws elbv2 describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn  LB_ARN
```

It might be the case that target does not contain any register instance but it still attached to LB.

So better to print all lister and rule of your LB and grep target ARN.

This will return the listener rule.

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:060558051165:listener/app/Stage-Main-LB/fab3ff1c37863309/cc0bc063f31b25ba | grep -A5 -B5 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:800371615020:targetgroup/api-test/2b44ce2b1a03c361'
```